# How do you hide/show forms based on select element using jQuery and Bootstrap v5

Tags: jquery, forms, function, display, bootstrap-5

I've created 5 forms and at the top of the page I have a `select` input. I've hidden the forms by wrapping them in a `div` element with the Bootstrap class `.d-none`. I'd like to be able to select an option from the drop-down and have the jQuery rehide the forms first then display the correct form.

So, far I've just been able to write a script to check `select_form`'s value.

***Bootstrap v5*** & ***jQuery v3.2.1***

```js
$('#select_form').on('change', function() {
  alert(this.value)
  /* 
   ** Hide ALL Forms (1-5) by adding .d-none class
   ** Check Value of Select
   ** Match Select Value to the correct form's ID
   ** Display the correct form by adding .d-block class
   */

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name='select_from' class='form-control' label='Select Form' id='select_report' list='form_list' defaulttext='(Please Select)' />
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_one'>Form Inputs Here</div>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_two'>Form Inputs Here</div>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_three'>Form Inputs Here</div>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_four'>Form Inputs Here</div>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_five'>Form Inputs Here</div>
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: The necessary steps are already listed in your script. You will definitely be able to find the necessary answers with your preferred search provider if you search for those single steps.

Comment: I made a snippet.  You had typos  - a fullstop after the alert and a space between `* /`
Please add relevant code for a [mcve]

Comment: Also the select has name="select_from" and not select_form but you use $("#...") which is accessing the ID of the select which in this case is select_report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really do need to take care in spelling

You have select_report as ID and select_from as name.

I use your ID here and toggle the d-none class OFF if the ID matches the text of the select

```js
$('#select_report').on('change', function() {
  const text = $("option:selected", this).text().toLowerCase();

  $(".form-row").each(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("d-none", this.id !== `form_${text}`)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name='select_form' class='form-control' label='Select Form' id='select_report' list='form_list' defaulttext='(Please Select)'>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_one'>Form 1 Inputs Here</div>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_two'>Form 2 Inputs Here</div>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_three'>Form 3 Inputs Here</div>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_four'>Form 4 Inputs Here</div>
<div class='form-row d-none' id='form_five'>Form 5 Inputs Here</div>
```